# wordpress jQuery.noConflict()

Tags: jquery, wordpress

wordpress include jquery.js but at the end of the script they have this line:

```
jQuery.noConflict()
```

So, I am not able to use $(), but I need to output js in footer and that script uses $.

How to set $?

Is this valid to do in footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (typeof $ === "undefined") {
       var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
   }
</script>
```

Or this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof $ === "undefined") {
      document.write('<script type="text/javascript"src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></'+'script>');
   }
</script>
```

But in second case there would two of the same jquery.js included in two diferent places just the last one without line:
    jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress is merely being a good neighbor. As the API docs state — `jQuery.noConflict()` does …

> relinquish jQuery's control of the `$` variable.

Many libraries and frameworks are making use of `$` and calling `jQuery.noConflict()` after defining your script ensures that all jQuery variables are removed from the global scope and that your code won’t interfere with anyone else’s.

I prefer to define my jQuery code in a closure — like this I’m able to use `$` as usual while not polluting the global namespace:

```
(function($) {

  // Code using `$` ...

})(jQuery);
```